# How to write like query in sqlite ,for iphone app

Tags: xcode, sqlite

I am bit confused about writing like query in a sample app for iphone .I am writing query like this as below but this does not help.I dont know where i am wrong in this query.

The str_Id i am passing is say july here as in db i am not saving the whole word july so i need to compare like the first 3 words in the query(So i cant use select * from  tbl where month = jul ,so i use the "like" query   )

```
        const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select  TourID, Tourname, Firstname, Lastname, Notes, Date, isSale, Image, SolidAmount, SolidDate, isPaid from SalesDataentry where Month like %@",str_Id]UTF8String];
```

Hope i am clear with my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out the [`NSPredicate` Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html), and also the [Introduction to Predicates Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789)

Comment: one I am not using core data i am using sqlite

Comment: @abhi I use `NSPredicate` when using sqlite, but there is probably a better way.

Comment: can u just tell me how to use for my above code it would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

try `%%@` instead of `%@`

```
const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select  TourID, Tourname, Firstname, Lastname, Notes, Date, isSale, Image, SolidAmount, SolidDate, isPaid from SalesDataentry where Month like %%@",str_Id]UTF8String];
```